# How to mark spacial tick mark in matplotlib and custom the gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib

My x-axis data starts from `100 to 1000 in step of 200`.
I want the x-axis tick marks as

```
100 200 400 600 800 1000.
```

Is there workaround to add the `100` at the start of x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(100,1001,20)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,x)

#create tick positions
tp=np.arange(0,1001,200)
tp[0]=100

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(tp)
fig.show()
```

[image]